# ssrs filter sharepoint list datasource for (blank)

Tags: ssrs-2012, sharepoint-list

I am creating a ssrs report consisting on data coming from sharepoint list so have created sharepoint list datasource.

Just wanted to know how to filter the data set for NOT taking `(null)/(blank)` values

tried to add filter while adding dataset as shown in below image.

[image]
but the filter for `(blank)` value is automatically getting reset to 
`(none)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Expression: `=IsNothing(Fields!ProposalRefID.Value)<>"True"`

Operator: `=`

Value: `="True"`

Or just create a new calculated field setting the above expression to filter by false values in this new field.